# Errno::ECONNREFUSED: Connection refused - connect(2) with Net::HTTP

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, net-http

I have my one server connecting to my other server (on a different machine) using net::http. When I use curl, it works (on localhost):

```
curl -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"user":{"email":"info@mysite.com","password":"password"}}' http://mysite.com:80/pages/account_stuff.json
=> {"account_id":4,"account_name":"Some Name","status":200}
```

On localhost, everything works fine. On one of my servers, a totally different scenerio.

When I use net::http on my ubuntu server, I get the Errno::ECONNREFUSED: Connection refused - connect(2):

```
url = "http://mysite.com:80/pages/account_stuff.json"
@uri = URI.parse(url)
@body = {"user" => {"email" => "info@mysite.com", "password" => "password"}}.to_json
@headers = {'Content-Type' => 'application/json'}
req = Net::HTTP::Post.new(@uri.to_s, initheader = @headers)
req.body = @body
http = Net::HTTP.new(@uri.host,@uri.port).start
Errno::ECONNREFUSED: Connection refused - connect(2)
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:762:in `initialize'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:762:in `open'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:762:in `block in connect'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/timeout.rb:54:in `timeout'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/timeout.rb:99:in `timeout'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:762:in `connect'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:755:in `do_start'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:750:in `start'
    from (irb):17
    from /home/mysite/public_html/store.mysite.com/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:47:in `start'
    from /home/mysite/public_html/store.mysite.com/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'
    from /home/mysite/public_html/store.mysite.com/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands.rb:41:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

Tried other post technique:

```
uri = URI.parse('http://mysite.com/pages/account_stuff.json')
res = Net::HTTP.post_form(uri, {"user" => {"email" => "info@mysite.com", "password" => "password"}})
Errno::ECONNREFUSED: Connection refused - connect(2)
```

Then tried net::http get request:

```
uri = URI('http://mysite.com/pages/account_stuff')
Net::HTTP.get(uri)
Errno::ECONNREFUSED: Connection refused - connect(2)
```

Then dropped net::http and tried with open::uri instead:

```
open("http://mysite.com")
Errno::ECONNREFUSED: Connection refused - connect(2)
```

Getting desperate now, tried  a basic curl request:

```
curl http://mysite.com
curl: (7) couldn't connect to host
```

Obviously, I realize this is no longer a ruby issue, and definitely not a curl issue. There must be some sort of firewall blocking traffic to the machine that server is on. I can connect to google just fine with curl but not that site.

Comment: `url = "http://mysite:80/pages/account_stuff.json"` doesn't look correct, should it be `url = "http://mysite.com:80/pages/account_stuff.json"`?

Comment: @Anand that was a typo when writing this question. In my code, the .com is there

Comment: is your code being executed from behind a firewall?

Comment: Yes it is, but as you see the curl command works

Comment: My apologies, I meant proxy. Curl will respect `http_proxy` environment variable and use it if defined (provided you are on a *nix o/s). While in Ruby you'll need to explicitly set the proxy via code using Net::HTTP::Proxy

Comment: There's only two machines here guarded by a firewall. THere's no proxy servers. Actually on the database server has a vpn and the database server isnt involved here.

Comment: I was blaming this on ruby, but I think this is a firewall issue, because I can't even connect to the site from my server using basic curl commands.

Comment: I'm seeing this error for open(URI.encode()) for certain sites and subdomains way outside of proxies and firewalls. That's not the issue.